# Android realm. Выдача items с диапазоном.

Tags: android, realm

```
protected void filteredEventsList() {
    String maxFree = ((FeedActivity)getActivity()).getMaxFree();
    int resultMaxFree = Integer.parseInt(maxFree);

    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<Event> eventRealmResults = realm.where(Event.class).equalTo("highestPrice", resultMaxFree).findAllSorted("startDate", Sort.ASCENDING);
    events = (ArrayList<Event>)realm.copyFromRealm(eventRealmResults.subList(0, eventRealmResults.size()));
    ((EventsListAdapter)eventsListView.getAdapter()).updateData(events);
    realm.close();
}
```

как можно в эту строчку добавить проверку "от" - "до".

```
RealmResults<Event> eventRealmResults = realm.where(Event.class).equalTo("highestPrice", resultMaxFree).findAllSorted("startDate", Sort.ASCENDING);
```

Например от 10 до 18 лет, и он выдает информацию кому есть от 10 до 18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо метода сравнения `equalTo()` Realm имеет такие методы, как:

`greaterThan()`, `greaterThanOrEqualTo()` - больше, больше либо равно

`lessThan()`, `lessThanOrEqualTo()` - меньше, меньше  либо равно

`between()` - между

в вашем случае запрос будет примерно таким:

```
RealmResults<Person> teenagers = realm.where(Person.class).between("age", 13, 20).findAll();
```

отобрать записи таблицы `Person` у которых поле `age` имеет значения от 13 до 20.

[Узнать больше](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#queries) о составлении запросов из официальной документации.